# Использование консоли MSYS2 для сборки проектов CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, msys2

Решил попробовать использовать MSYS2 в качестве единого хранилища всех тулзов для сборки и компиляции разных проектов. Простенькие проекты без зависимостей с помощью CMake собираются спокойно, но вот с зависимостями - проблемы постоянные.

Решил сделать маленький проект на SFML, соответственно взял уже скомпиленную библиотеку, слинковал в своем проекте нужные зависимости, кроме одной, которую MSYS2 в упор не может найти для CMake (может проблема и не в msys2, но Clion со своим cmake спокойно собирает проект) - opengl

Часть кода из CMakeLists.txt:

```
# ....
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
set(SFML_DIR "${PROJECT_EXTLIBS_DIR}/lib-SFML/lib/cmake/SFML")

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS system window network graphics audio main REQUIRED)
# ....
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME}
    sfml-system
    sfml-window
    sfml-network
    sfml-graphics
    sfml-audio
    sfml-main
    ${PROJECT_EXTLIBS_DIR}/lib-SFML/lib/libFLAC.a
    ${PROJECT_EXTLIBS_DIR}/lib-SFML/lib/libfreetype.a
    ${PROJECT_EXTLIBS_DIR}/lib-SFML/lib/libogg.a
    ${PROJECT_EXTLIBS_DIR}/lib-SFML/lib/libopenal32.a
    ${PROJECT_EXTLIBS_DIR}/lib-SFML/lib/libvorbis.a
    ${PROJECT_EXTLIBS_DIR}/lib-SFML/lib/libvorbisenc.a
    ${PROJECT_EXTLIBS_DIR}/lib-SFML/lib/libvorbisfile.a
    )
```

В $PATH у MSYS2 скопирован Windows $PATH.
Компиляция:

```sh
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="clang.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="clang++.exe" ..

/* ... */

CMake Error at extlibs/lib-SFML/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake:139 (message):
  SFML found but some of its dependencies are missing ( OpenGL)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /d/Projects/testproject/extlibs/lib-SFML/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake

  but it set SFML_FOUND to FALSE so package "SFML" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Clion, соответственно, без каких либо проблем собирает этот проект.

На сколько я понял CMake не может найти что-то похожее на libopengl32.a

Итак сам вопрос:
В чем может быть проблема с невозможностью нахождения OpenGL (сам .a файл я нашел в папке с msys2) и как это исправить?

Comment: Это странно - использовать find_package и вручную прописывать пути к либам вместо переменных, которые экспортирует SFMLConfig.cmake. И Вы можете вручную посмотреть этот файл, может тогда понятно станет где SFML зависимости ищет. И вообще как он их ищет.

Comment: SFML_DIR необходим, чтобы cmake нашёл файл SFMLConfig.cmake. Я не устанавливаю SFML в систему, а сохраняю локальную скомпиленную версию. Меня волнует то, что cmake не может найти opengl. SFMLConfig.cmake его ищет, на сколько я могу понять, стандартным Find Opengl.cmake, но все равно не находит